# Can I get Linkedin profile active status via API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, linkedin-api

Can I get profile active status(green dot) of any public profile via API?
Also, can I get connections profile list of some public profile after user guaranteed Auth to my LinkedIn app? I want to get the active status of all connections of some profile!

i can't find any info about active status in `r_basicprofile` and `r_fullprofile`

Answer (score 0):

1. There is currently no public API from LinkedIn that can get active status of a public profile. Users can also opt out for showing their green dots from settings.
2. It's possible to get connection list using API: `GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&start=0&count=50` Here is the API Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api